# Does Strapi Support Local Registration and then login through a different provider like google or facebook?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, strapi

Does Strapi support local registration and then login through a different provider like google or facebook?

Answer (score 4):

by default it's not possible.

You have one authentication per support.

After that, you are free to customize the auth provider function of the Users-Permissions plugin to check if the email of this user is already used and in this case use this user.

Here is the concept of customization - https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/customization.html#plugin-extensions

And here is the auth provider login function - https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js#L144